# trying to use OpenCV for a C++ project, but I can't get #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp> to work

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

when i try to include opencv.hpp into my file, it says that it cannot open source file.

main.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    
    printf("hello world");
   
    return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(exposure-correction VERSION 0.1.0)

include(CTest)
enable_testing() 

set(OpenCV_DIR C:/Users/mudit/OneDrive/Documents/opencv/build)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS C:/Users/mudit/OneDrive/Documents/opencv/build/include) 

add_executable(exposure-correction src/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(exposure-correction ${OpenCV_LIBS})
 
set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

CMake finds OpenCV successfully:

```
[cmake] -- OpenCV ARCH: x64
[cmake] -- OpenCV RUNTIME: vc16
[cmake] -- OpenCV STATIC: OFF
[cmake] -- Found OpenCV 4.8.0 in C:/Users/mudit/OneDrive/Documents/opencv/build/x64/vc16/lib
```

But when I include it in my cpp file it says:

> cannot open source file "opencv2/opencv.hpp"C/C++(1696)

I have added both bin and lib directories from opencv into my system path variables.

Anyone know what to do?

Comment: Is the `opencv2` folder in `C:/Users/mudit/OneDrive/Documents/opencv/build/include` ?

Comment: `include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )` ? You forgot `${...}`

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson yes